# Parse.com not saving images greater than 400KB

Tags: java, android, image, parse-platform, imageview

I am having trouble uploading image in imageview that i get from phone gallery to the parse.com database. Parse says the file limit is 10MB. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
ParseFile imgFile = new ParseFile(fullName+"_"+emp+".jpeg", bite_image);
imgFile.saveInBackground();

ParseObject teamTable = new ParseObject("TeamsTable");
teamTable.put("Team", team);
teamTable.put("Name", fullName);
teamTable.put("images", imgFile);
teamTable.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

@Override
public void done(ParseException e) {
   if (e == null) {
      startActivity(new Intent(RegisterForm.this, Login.class));
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful Registration!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      finish();


     } else {
     }
     }
  });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?? you also do not need to upload your File separately, it can be done in one step when saving an Object.

Comment: Place the ParseObject save in the done() method of the callback of the ParseFile saveInBackground, this makes sure your image is saved on Parse before saving the entire object.

Comment: @TheTool I also save the ParseFile and ParseObject in an AsyncTask. Why does the onPostExecute() execute before the ParseObject saveInBackground is completed?

Comment: @MoNazemi I also save the ParseFile and ParseObject in an AsyncTask. Why does the onPostExecute() execute before the ParseObject saveInBackground is completed?

Comment: Because they run on different threads, saveInBackground() makes sure your main thread does not get blocked by opening a new thread and saving the file or object. To counter this, call the saveInBackground() of the ParseObject in the SaveCallBack of the ParseFile. That way you make sure that one thread finishes before the other and already finishes the activity while the other one is still running.

Comment: That worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first save a PFFile containing your image, then add this PFFile to your object.

```
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.jpg" data:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.)];
[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (succeeded) {
      // Add the file to your object and save your object
```